# Using does verb

Tags: phrase-usage

What is the difference between:
"It does finish successfully" versus "It finishes successfully"
What is the difference and what's commonly used.

Comment: Using *does* adds emphasis to the fact that it finished successfully, as opposed to *it does not finish successfully*. *It finishes successfully* merely explains how it finishes, without any stress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary difference is emphasis.

> Given X, Y and Z, the algorithm finishes successfully.

This is a fine, acceptable and complete sentence.

> Given X, Y and Z, the algorithm does finish successfully.

The word *does* here adds emphasis.  This refutes the negative case (where the algorithm does *not* finish successfully).  It would mostly make sense if you also want to talk about the cases in which the algorithm doesn't finish successfully (or doesn't finish).  E.g.,

> Without rain, strawberries cannot grow.  However, in the right conditions, strawberries do grow without much human intervention.